# digital audio workstation with API

Tags: api, audio

Do you know any digital audio workstation that has API? I would like to create application that can generate music based on such programs possibility. This is purely for my own entertainment, I don't mean to make any kind of commercial moves...

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? Reascript for Reaper (mentioned by Picnic Tripper) seems to be just a scripting package and not an API that exposes Reaper functionality to other apps. I want to be able to control a multi-channel music player (e.g. a DAW) from a separate program, ideally a python one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different DAW's you can look at that allow you to interface with a variety of languages. The main ones that spring to mind are Reaper and Ableton. As far as I know, Ableton uses python internally and some clever people have found ways of taking advantage of that here;

https://code.google.com/p/liveapi/

The other one is Reaper, which allows you to script its internal features using Python using something called ReaScript;

http://www.reaper.fm/sdk/reascript/reascript.php

Hope that helps.